# Word for side scenes on a road

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm using a metaphor that compares the process of learning to a journey on a road. I want to say that the true purpose of learning a subject is to enjoy it / enrich your life, not to get good grades / win awards. So the sentence is

The excitement of getting good grades and winning awards are only possible _____ on the road.

I want to put a word that means something like side scenes or "byproducts" but what's a good word to use in this case that fits with the road metaphor?

Comment: How about *detours*?  Shifting your focus to them takes you away from what your main goal should be.  Or, perhaps you think that those things are nice *scenic vistas* along the way- not necessary but certainly not objectionable.  Of course there are those who say life is all about the journey and not the destination.

Answer (score 2):

The excitement of getting good grades and winning awards are only possible [waypoints](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/waypoint) on the road.

Waypoint is especially applicable to exams, as after an exam you typically take a break and assess your progress before continuing with your studies or career.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you want is **glimpses**.

> Glimpse : to see something or someone for a very short time or only partly

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/glimpse)

> glimpses of lighted interiors seen as I walked along city streets at night

[Edward Hopper](http://quotes.yourdictionary.com/author/edward-hopper/165243#glimpses) . . . . .
The idea for the painting ‘Room in New York’, 1932.

Answer (score 1):

How about the word, "byways"?

Miriam Webster defines a "byway" as

1: a little traveled side road

2: a secondary or little known aspect or field

*meandering more and more in the fascinating byways of learning—* The Times Literary Supplement (London)

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/byway